# How to add a popup in leaflet in R with an if and a function?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm making some maps in R with leaflet and I'm counting points on a buffer by some years. Now I'm putting that polygons in the map and all the points and I'm adding the layers to the map.

So, my problem is that I want that when I select or unselect a year on the layer this action sum or rest the total count in the buffer.

How can I make this in one map instead of making several maps for year?

```
# Counting points
BUF_2014 <- gBuffer(LOCATI,width = 0.00182, byid = TRUE)
count_2014 <- over(BUF_2014, GEO_2014, fn=length)
BUF_2014$count <- count_2014$NRO
... # Do this with 2015,2016,2017,2018

# Buffer
BUF <- rbind(BUF_2014,BUF_2015,BUF_2016,
             BUF_2017,BUF_2018)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(GEO_2014@coords[,1],GEO_2014@coords[,2],
                   group = "2014", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(GEO_2015@coords[,1],GEO_2015@coords[,2],
                   group = "2015", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(GEO_2016@coords[,1],GEO_ACCIDENTE_2016@coords[,2],
                   group = "2016", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(GEO_2017@coords[,1],GEO_2017@coords[,2],
                   group = "2017", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(GEO_2018@coords[,1],GEO_2018@coords[,2],
                   group = "2018", clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()) %>%
  addPolygons(data = BUF, 
              popup=~paste(count)) %>%
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("2014","2015","2016","2017","2018"))
```

I'm just getting the 5 polygons by year and the count of just one year, and I just want one polygon with the sum of the counts by adding or removing layers.

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7GHe.jpg)

[Map2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0jW6.jpg)